# Adding separating line to table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, book-design

There's so many small chapters in the book I am publishing, that I've altered the appearance of the ToC. I'm happy with the results, only, I want to add a line to visually separate the `mainmatter` from the `frontmatter` and the `backmatter` chapters. On the left is what I have now, but on the right is what I'm looking for.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, paper=156mm:235mm, BCOR=12mm, headings=optiontotocandhead, headings=openany]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{headings=small}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  beforeskip=.4em plus 1pt,
  pagenumberformat=\textbf,
  linefill={\Dotfill},
]{tocline}{chapter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Dotfill}{\leavevmode \leaders \hb@xt@ 0.75em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern  \z@}
\makeatother

\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}%Indexing package
\makeindex[intoc,options= -s index_style.ist,name=m,title=\mbox{Index},columns=2]
\makeindex[options= -s index_style2.ist, intoc,name=r,title=\mbox{Appendix A: Initial Publication \& Grouping of Lectures},columns=1]

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{Alegreya,AlegreyaSans} 
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\AlegreyaOsF #1}}

\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\newglossary*{contemp}{Murids from Inayat Khan's Time}
\newglossary*{list}{List of Persons, Places, Works, etc.}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{adab}
    {
        name=adab,
        description={Arabic, Persian, Urdu, good manners, politeness, respect},
        text=\emph{adab},
        sort=adab
    }
\newglossaryentry{Akbar}
    {
        name={Akbar, aka Akbar the Great},
        description={(1542–1605) \ldots},
        text=Akbar,
        sort=Akbar,
        type=list
    }
\newglossaryentry{allen}
    {
        name={Allen, Lillian},
        description={An English pupil from the early London period.  She lived in Southampton, UK where there was a Sufi Centre and her address appears in Inayat Khan’s address books for the UK},
        type=contemp,
        text=Lillian Allen,
        sort=Allen Lillian
    }

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\newpage
\tableofcontents
    \begin{center}
        \rule{.8\textwidth}{0.5pt}
        \rule{.8\textwidth}{0.5pt}
    \end{center}
\addchap{Preface}

\mainmatter
\addchap{There Are Over 100 Chapters} \gls{allen}
\addchap{In This Book} \gls{Akbar}
\addchap{That's Why I Wanted Them} \gls{adab}
\addchap{This Close to Each Other} \index[m]{indexitem}
\addchap{In the Table of Content} \index[r]{other kind of index}

\backmatter
\newpage
\printindex[r]\label{appendix}
\printglossary[toctitle=\mbox{Glossary of Foreign Words}, nonumberlist]
\printglossary[type=list, toctitle=\mbox{List of Persons, Places, Works, etc.}]
\printglossary[type=contemp, toctitle=\mbox{Mureeds from Inayat Khan's Time}, nonumberlist]
\printindex[m]

\end{document}
```

With `index_style.ist`:

```
headings_flag 1

heading_prefix "\n\\raggedright\\large\\sffamily\\normalfont%
\\noindent\\textbf{"heading_suffix "}\\par\\nopagebreak\n"

item_0 "\n \\item \\small "

delim_0 " \\Dotfill "
delim_1 " \\Dotfill "
delim_2 " \\Dotfill "
```

and `index_style2.ist`:

```
item_0 "\n \\item \\small "

delim_0 " \\Dotfill "
delim_1 " \\Dotfill "
delim_2 " \\Dotfill "
```

Comment: `\addtocontents{toc}{\begin{center}\rule{.8\textwidth}{0.5pt}\end{center}}` right after `\mainmatter` or `\backmatter`?

Comment: @frabjous Might yo think of turning this into an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: @PeterWilson Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command `\addtocontents{toc}{...}` to add arbitrary code to the .toc file at a certain point in the document as it's being written.

In your case, I might define a command that could be reused. Using something similar to the code you suggested to produce the rule and center it, this might be something like:

```
\newcommand{\inserttocseparator}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\begin{center}\rule{.8\textwidth}{0.5pt}\end{center}}
}
```

You could then use the `\inserttocseparator` command in your document at the places corresponding to where in the ToC you want to insert a line. As you described what you want, this could be right after `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter`:

```
\mainmatter\inserttocseparator
```

And

```
\backmatter\inserttocseparator
```

The result looks like this:

[image: with center environment]

It's a matter of taste, but the `center` environment produces gaps above and below the lines that are perhaps a bit too big. An alternative might be:

```
\newcommand{\inserttocseparator}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\par\hspace*{0.1\textwidth}\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.5pt}\par}
}
```

The result is more compact:

[image: with par commands]

You could play around with `\vspace*` commands and the like inside the definition of `\inserttocseparator` if you want to fine tune that.

Here's the full document used to produce the above for reference:

```
\documentclass[10pt, paper=156mm:235mm, BCOR=12mm, headings=optiontotocandhead, headings=openany]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{headings=small}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  beforeskip=.4em plus 1pt,
  pagenumberformat=\textbf,
  linefill={\Dotfill},
]{tocline}{chapter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Dotfill}{\leavevmode \leaders \hb@xt@ 0.75em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern  \z@}
\makeatother

\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}%Indexing package
\makeindex[intoc,options= -s index_style.ist,name=m,title=\mbox{Index},columns=2]
\makeindex[options= -s index_style2.ist, intoc,name=r,title=\mbox{Appendix A: Initial Publication \& Grouping of Lectures},columns=1]

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{Alegreya,AlegreyaSans} 
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\AlegreyaOsF #1}}

\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\newglossary*{contemp}{Murids from Inayat Khan's Time}
\newglossary*{list}{List of Persons, Places, Works, etc.}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{adab}
    {
        name=adab,
        description={Arabic, Persian, Urdu, good manners, politeness, respect},
        text=\emph{adab},
        sort=adab
    }
\newglossaryentry{Akbar}
    {
        name={Akbar, aka Akbar the Great},
        description={(1542–1605) \ldots},
        text=Akbar,
        sort=Akbar,
        type=list
    }
\newglossaryentry{allen}
    {
        name={Allen, Lillian},
        description={An English pupil from the early London period.  She lived in Southampton, UK where there was a Sufi Centre and her address appears in Inayat Khan’s address books for the UK},
        type=contemp,
        text=Lillian Allen,
        sort=Allen Lillian
    }

\newcommand{\inserttocseparator}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\par\hspace*{0.1\textwidth}\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.5pt}\par}
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\newpage
\tableofcontents

\addchap{Preface}

\mainmatter\inserttocseparator
\addchap{There Are Over 100 Chapters} \gls{allen}
\addchap{In This Book} \gls{Akbar}
\addchap{That's Why I Wanted Them} \gls{adab}
\addchap{This Close to Each Other} \index[m]{indexitem}
\addchap{In the Table of Content} \index[r]{other kind of index}

\backmatter\inserttocseparator
\newpage
\printindex[r]\label{appendix}
\printglossary[toctitle=\mbox{Glossary of Foreign Words}, nonumberlist]
\printglossary[type=list, toctitle=\mbox{List of Persons, Places, Works, etc.}]
\printglossary[type=contemp, toctitle=\mbox{Mureeds from Inayat Khan's Time}, nonumberlist]
\printindex[m]

\end{document}
```